# Box plots not appearing properly in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am creating box plots within R, however, they are appearing incorrectly. My data is based off of German Credit Dataset on Kaggle.

My code with two different attributes trying to be tested:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Creditability, y = Purpose, fill = Creditability)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  ggtitle("Creditability vs Purpose")


data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Creditability, y = Account.Balance, fill = Creditability)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  ggtitle("Creditability vs Account Balance")
```

I've tried a few of the different attributes for it, but results in the [same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS3UE.png)

[image: same error]

Edited info: Is it because the attributes have too much information? I have split the sample into test (300) vs train (700) and I am currently using train. Would it simply be because there's too much info?

Edit picture:

[Factors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Lra.jpg)

Edit for graph error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ayFf.jpg)

Comment: looks like `data$Purpose` is a `factor`, the y variable in a boxplot should be continuous, compare: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), factor(mpg))) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand this correctly, but I should swap my x and y variables?

Comment: no, if purpose is supposed to be the y variable, you can `ggplot(data, aes(x = Creditability, y = as.numeric(Purpose), ...)` and see if that is the correct result. a box plot with a discrete y-axis variable seems odd. or maybe `as.numeric(as.character(Purpose))` is correct

Comment: Oh! That's lovely, thank you so much for your help! Just to make sure I am understanding this correctly, is it because I had converted all the data to factors, I have to ensure to have is.numeric() because it can't plot something that is not numeric?

Comment: Edit: Okay, so I noticed something, any factor w less than 4 levels doesn't show. Would there be a way to fix this?

Comment: that does not seem right but i'm not exactly sure what you mean. also factors (or characters) should only be the x variable, the y should be integer, numeric, continuous, etc

Comment: Okay so I added a picture named Factors, unless it's just a correlation I made by sheer chance. But any of the levels that are under 4, the graph does not appear for them

Comment: can you add a picture of the graph? if all of your data are factors, i would think a barplot or another type of figure would make more sense than a boxplot

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained in the comments, you cannot show boxplots where the y axis is set to be a factor.  Factors are by their nature *discrete* variables, even if the levels are named as numbers.  In order to utilize the stat function for the boxplot geom, you need the y axis to be continuous and the x axis to be discrete (or able to be separated into discrete values via the `group=` aesthetic).

Let me demonstrate with the `mtcars` dataset built into `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(carb), y=mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Here we can draw boxpots because the x aesthetic is forced to be discrete (via `factor(carb)`), while the y axis is using `mpg` which is a numeric column in the `mtcars` dataset.

If you set both `carb` and `mpg` to be factors, you get something that should look pretty similar to what you're seeing:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(carb), y=factor(mpg))) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

In your case, all your columns in your dataset are factors.  If they are factors that can be coerced to be numbers, you can turn them into continuous vectors via using `as.numeric(levels(column_name)[column_name])`.  Alternatively, you can use `as.numeric(as.character(column_name))`.  Here's what it looks like to first convert the `mtcars$mpg` column to a factor of numeric values, and then back to being only numeric via this method.

```
df <- mtcars

# convert to a factor
df$mpg <- factor(df$mpg)

# back to numeric!
df$mpg <- as.numeric(levels(df$mpg)[df$mpg])

# this plot looks like it did before when we did the same with mtcars
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(carb), y=mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
```

So, for your case, do this two step process:

```
data$Purpose <- as.numeric(levels(data$Purpose)[data$Purpose])

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Creditability, y = Purpose, fill = Creditability)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  ggtitle("Creditability vs Purpose")
```

That should work.  You can follow in a similar fashion for your other variables.